# Cannot find control with name: 'userName' while using @elementClass of rxweb validators

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am using @elementClass decorator of @rxweb/reactive-form-validators and i am getting error like this

`Cannot find control with name: 'userName'`

And here is my model class

> export class User {    @elementClass({       conditionalExpression:
>   function        (c) {           return this.password ==
>   "complex" && c.dirty == true ?            'ng-invalid' : '';       }})
>   userName: string;    @prop()   password: string;}

This is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3df1em?embed=1&file=src/app/user.model.ts). What am i missing in this?

Comment: Can you share the editable URL of Stackblitz?

Comment: Stackblitz is already there in the question

Comment: Which is in *non-editable* mode I guess!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Updated the link in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `@prop()` decorator to your `userName` formComtrol. @elementClass decorator will set the class conditionally to the formControl.

So the `user.model.ts` Code will be:

```
import { prop, elementClass } from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators"
import { AbstractControl } from "@angular/forms"

export class User {
  @prop()
  @elementClass({
    conditionalExpression: function (c) {
      return this.password == "complex" && c.dirty == true ? 'ng-invalid' : '';
    }
  })

  userName: string;

  @prop()
  password: string;
}
```

[`Here`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edyiab?embed=1&file=src/app/user.model.ts) is the working stackblitz